# Как получить строку из терминала в скрипт?

Tags: php, cmd, terminal, exec, serial

Собираюсь скриптом php отправлять AT команду usb модему на получение баланса по ussd. С командами разобрался, ответ тоже получаю (но зашифрованный).

Появилось несколько вопросов:

1. С помощью какой команды заставить терминал выполнить команду AT? команду собираюсь отправлять с помощью `exec`

   Попробовал такой вариант `putty -serial com7 AT+CUSD=1,"AA180C3602",15` но ничего не происходит
2. После отправки запроса, через некоторое время приходит ответ в терминал, как его потом получить в скрипт для дальнейшей обработки?